# What spell list available to a level 2 ranger is most useful against undead?

Tags: spells, undead, ranger, middle-earth-role-playing

In the  campaign I am currently participating in I play a level 2 ranger. The GM has informed us through an NPC that we will be heading into a large expanse of ghost, skeleton, and Barrow Wight infested land. I was wondering what spell lists available to a 2nd level ranger would help me stay alive or kill undead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At level 2 there's not much a Ranger can do magically against an undead. Rangers are secondary utility spellcasters in MERP so your choice of spells is pretty limited, they're allowed the base Ranger spell lists or the open channelling spell lists and only levels 1-5 for the open lists; at level 2 you're not going to be casting any of these particularly quickly or often and they don't last long (usually 1 min/level).

That said I'd recommend the following spell lists: (Number == spell level)

**Surface Ways**

1. Heal 10 - Heals 1-10 hits. Healing, nuff said.

**Protections** (One target)

1. Prayer - 1 min level +10 bonus to RR, useful for defense.
2. Bless - 1 min level +10 bonus to DB - that will help keep you alive.

**Natures Lore**

2. Natures Awareness - Duration concentration 100' radius - Allows caster to monitor "activity" in the area - useful for finding bad guys

**In general; For the base rangers lists**

- Path mastery - This is really useful for tracking and following people. Best ranger list. This -may- be useful for determining where the danger spots are and avoiding them!
- Nature's ways - Only slightly useful, you can probably use tracking for most of it instead.
- Moving ways - Just about useless, unless you're running around in trees or can't swim.
- Nature's guises - Decent spell list, great for setting up ambushes.

When fighting undead in MERP, try and engage at a distance first to find out if your weapons will even work on them, they're very very dangerous especially at low levels; your best bet is to try and avoid them or kill them from a distance or with fire; if you get in combat parry and hope someone else can smack it while you "distract" it.

Undead also often have life draining (CON) abilities and will be very tough to kill and criticals will have reduced effect on them.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob. I just posted a new MERP question and i think you are basically the only person on regularly who can answer it. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: I'll take a look :)